# Given: 2 lines containing the diameter of a circle and a point lying on this circle; Find: the equation of this circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, circles

The lines $ y = \frac{4}{3}x - \frac{5}{3} $ and $ y = \frac{-4}{3}x - \frac{13}{3} $ each contain diameters of a circle. and the point $ (-5, 0) $ is also on that circle.

**Find the equation of this circle.**

Comment: Note that [someone already asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831577/given-2-lines-containing-the-diameter-of-a-circle-and-a-point-lying-on-this-circ) this question. However, it was on-hold when it was not really eligible, and never was taken off on-hold after I made it sensical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Prerequisites

---

**Given**

- We have 2 lines with given equations (see below).

  - $ y = \frac{4}{3}x - \frac{5}{3} $
  - $ y = \frac{-4}{3}x - \frac{13}{3} $
- These lines each contain a diameter of the circle-in-question.
- We have a point with the given coordinate (see below).

  - $ P = (-5, 0) $
- This point is on the circle in question.

---

**Problem**

Find the equation of the circle-in-question.

*Here is our progress:*

$ (x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2 $

---

### Solution

---

**Step 1**

*Let us find the center of the circle-in-question.*

Note that diameters of circles go through the center of a circle.

We can find the intersection of the two given lines.

*Let us find the x-component of the center of the circle-in-question.*

$ \frac{4}{3}x - \frac{5}{3} = \frac{-4}{3}x - \frac{13}{3} $

$ 4x - 5 = -4x - 13 $

$ 8x = -8 $

$ x = -1 $

*Let us find the y-component of the center of the circle-in-question.*

$
y 
= \frac{4}{3}x - \frac{5}{3} 
= \frac{4}{3}(-1) - \frac{5}{3} 
= \frac{-4}{3} - \frac{5}{3}
= \frac{-9}{3}
= -3
$

*So...*

The center of the circle-in-question is $ Q = (-1, -3) $.

*Here is our progress:*

$ (x - (-1))^2 + (y - (-3))^2 = r^2 $

$ (x + 1)^2 + (y + 3)^2 = r^2 $

---

**Step 2**

*Let us find the radius of the circle-in-question.*

We know that the radius of the circle-in-question is the distance between the center of the circle-in-question and the given point that lies on the circle-in-question.

*Let us find the distance between such points.*

$
l 
= \sqrt{((-1)-(-5))^2+((-3)-(0))^2}
= \sqrt{(4)^2+(-3)^2}
= \sqrt{16+9}
= \sqrt{25}
= 5
$

*So...*

The length of the radius is $ r = 5 $

*Here is our progress:*

$ (x + 1)^2 + (y + 3)^2 = (5)^2 $
$ (x + 1)^2 + (y + 3)^2 = 25 $

---

### Answer

---

The equation of the circle-in-question is:

$$ (x + 1)^2 + (y + 3)^2 = 25 $$

Comment: This is wrong. The problem says $(-5,0)$ is on the circle, but your solution (**Step 2**) assumes $(0,-5)$ is on the circle.

Comment: @NobleMushtak - Oh, my bad! Let me go ahead and correct it. Thanks for the notice.